# Cabal error: Failed to load interface for `Control.Lens.Type'

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-lens

Can't build trifecta-1.5.2

ghc-pkg check shows no borken packages

error:

```
[ 8 of 13] Compiling Text.Trifecta.Highlight ( src\Text\Trifecta\Highlight.hs, dist\build\Text\Trifecta\Highlight.o )

src\Text\Trifecta\Highlight.hs:73:1:
    Failed to load interface for `Control.Lens.Type'
    no package key matching `lens-4.13-3NqKPNVtlmaitmhxgiGFMb' was found
    In the type `lens-4.13-3NqKPNVtlmaitmhxgiGFMb:Control.Lens.Type.Lens' c_aJqo HighlightedRope'
    In the class declaration for `HasHighlightedRope'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
```

Windows 10

```
F:\>ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3

F:\>cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.23.0.0
compiled using version 1.23.0.0 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: `Cabal` 1.23.0.0 is a development version, so your installation might be in very inconsistent state, there was development related ti package keys in particular. Is this happening inside a fresh sandbox?

Comment: @phadej it's not sandbox, do you think it's related recent cabal updates?

Comment: It might be, could you try in the empty sandbox?

Comment: @phadej do you mean just older cabal.exe or for some reason completely new environment?

Comment: well, both would help. But could you just create a new sandbox and try `cabal install trifecta` there?

Comment: Starting a new sandbox in a folder is something like `cabal sandbox init` if that helps.